# Customizing Istio metrics results in duplicated metrics

Tags: prometheus, istio, envoyproxy

I want to add `request.url_path` and `request.method` information to the `istio_request_total` metric by using an EnvoyFilter.

**Istio Version: 1.8.5**

Using my EnvoyFilter duplicates `istio_requests_total` metric by adding `envoy_request_path__$(path-seperated-with-dashes)__` prefix.

Below is the EnvoyFilter I use

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: customize-requests-total-metric
spec:
  configPatches:
    - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER
      match:
        context: SIDECAR_OUTBOUND
        listener:
          filterChain:
            filter:
              name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
              subFilter:
                name: istio.stats
        proxy:
          proxyVersion: ^1\.8.*
      patch:
        operation: REPLACE
        value:
          name: istio.stats
          typed_config:
            "@type": type.googleapis.com/udpa.type.v1.TypedStruct
            type_url: type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.wasm.v3.Wasm
            value:
              config:
                configuration:
                  "@type": type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.StringValue
                  value: |
                    {
                      "debug": "true",
                      "stat_prefix": "istio",
                      "metrics": [
                        {
                          "name": "requests_total",
                          "dimensions": {
                            "request_path": "request.url_path",
                            "request_method": "request.method"
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                root_id: stats_outbound
                vm_config:
                  code:
                    local:
                      inline_string: envoy.wasm.stats
                  runtime: envoy.wasm.runtime.null
                  vm_id: stats_outbound
    - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER
      match:
        context: SIDECAR_INBOUND
        listener:
          filterChain:
            filter:
              name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
              subFilter:
                name: istio.stats
        proxy:
          proxyVersion: ^1\.8.*
      patch:
        operation: REPLACE
        value:
          name: istio.stats
          typed_config:
            "@type": type.googleapis.com/udpa.type.v1.TypedStruct
            type_url: type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.wasm.v3.Wasm
            value:
              config:
                configuration:
                  "@type": type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.StringValue
                  value: |
                    {
                      "debug": "true",
                      "stat_prefix": "istio",
                      "metrics": [
                        {
                          "name": "requests_total",
                          "dimensions": {
                            "request_path": "request.url_path",
                            "request_method": "request.method"
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                root_id: stats_inbound
                vm_config:
                  code:
                    local:
                      inline_string: envoy.wasm.stats
                  runtime: envoy.wasm.runtime.null
                  vm_id: stats_inbound
```

This duplicates `istio_requests_total` metric by adding `envoy_request_path__$(path-seperated-with-dashes)__` prefix. Below is an example of it.

```
# TYPE envoy_request_path____catalog_lint___istio_requests_total counter
envoy_request_path____catalog_lint___istio_requests_total{response_code="200",reporter="destination",source_workload="my-service",source_workload_namespace="my-namespace",source_principal="unknown",source_app="my-service",source_version="unknown",destination_workload="api-linter",destination_workload_namespace="my-namespace",destination_principal="unknown",destination_app="my-service",destination_version="unknown",destination_service="my-service",destination_service_name="my-service",destination_service_namespace="my-namespace",request_protocol="http",response_flags="-",grpc_response_status="",connection_security_policy="none",source_canonical_service="my-service",destination_canonical_service="api-linter",source_canonical_revision="latest",destination_canonical_revision="latest",request_method="GET"} 4204
```

**
My question is, how can I add request path as a label to the main `istio_requests_total` metric like I did for `request_method="GET"` in the example above?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `url_path` and `method` are not part of the [`DefaultStatTags`](https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/release-1.8/pkg/bootstrap/config.go) that get extracted automatically.

To make it work, you must add the `extraStatTags` annotation (`sidecar.istio.io/extraStatTags: request_path,request_method`) to the deployment (or configure it mesh-wide via mesh config). See the [example in the docs](https://istio.io/v1.8/docs/tasks/observability/metrics/customize-metrics/).

Also, you should consider upgrading to the newer version of Istio as 1.8 was released in 2020 and not supported anymore.

Comment: You're right but looks like I forgot to mention that I already added you said. That's how I made it work for `method`. My problem is metrics are getting duplicated with request path prefixes but it's not the case for request method. I successfully added method as a label but not request path.